# I got error 255 , when i doing initial commit. Mercurial TortoiseHg

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

Good day. Tell me please, why i have error 255, when i doing initial commit, error on scr. When I commit in parts of 2-4 files, it works, and when all the files are completely, it gives an error.

[src error 255](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4TUO.png)

And on the other server everything is fine. Tell me what could be the problem?
Server data: Apache 2.4.41, PHP 7.4.3, MySQL Ver 8.0.22-0, NodeJS v15.8.0, Samba, ubuntu 20.04

Text of error

```
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 5.0.2)
** Extensions loaded: tortoisehg.util.hgcommands, tortoisehg.util.partialcommit, tortoisehg.util.pipeui, tortoisehg.util.win32ill, tortoisehg.util.hgdispatch
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 5.0.2)
** Extensions loaded: tortoisehg.util.hgcommands, tortoisehg.util.partialcommit, tortoisehg.util.pipeui, tortoisehg.util.win32ill, tortoisehg.util.hgdispatch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hg", line 50, in <module>
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 99, in run
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 225, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 376, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 384, in _callcatch
  File "mercurial\scmutil.pyo", line 167, in callcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 367, in _runcatchfunc
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1021, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 756, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1030, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1018, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1680, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 5300, in serve
  File "mercurial\server.pyo", line 147, in runservice
  File "mercurial\commandserver.pyo", line 405, in run
  File "mercurial\commandserver.pyo", line 346, in serve
  File "mercurial\commandserver.pyo", line 319, in serveone
  File "mercurial\commandserver.pyo", line 303, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 225, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 376, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 384, in _callcatch
  File "mercurial\scmutil.pyo", line 167, in callcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 367, in _runcatchfunc
  File "tortoisehg\util\hgdispatch.pyo", line 23, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1021, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 756, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1030, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1018, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1680, in check
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1680, in check
  File "tortoisehg\util\partialcommit.pyo", line 34, in partialcommit
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1680, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1647, in commit
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1722, in _docommit
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyo", line 2434, in commit
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1720, in commitfunc
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 177, in wrapper
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 2548, in commit
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 177, in wrapper
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 2622, in commitctx
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 2434, in _filecommit
  File "mercurial\filelog.pyo", line 135, in add
  File "mercurial\filelog.pyo", line 106, in addrevision
  File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 1905, in addrevision
  File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 1916, in addrawrevision
  File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 544, in _indexfp
  File "mercurial\store.pyo", line 571, in __call__
  File "mercurial\vfs.pyo", line 420, in __call__
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 2314, in makedirs
WindowsError: [Error 50] : '\\\\vsrvdev1\\web\\sez\\dev\\.hg/store\\data/~f4~fb~e2'
cmdserver: процесс завершился неожиданно с кодом 255
```

Comment: This does not seem to be on topic as documented in [help/on-topic]. Also please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447).

Comment: ok, add text error

Comment: Can you please add the exact hg command that you used? Or describe exactly what you did in THG?

Comment: @OlafKock what makes you say this is off topic?

Comment: @StayOnTarget it's predominantly the configuration nature of the question (see the [tag:apache] tag description) and the lack of steps to reproduce. Based on the (irrelevant) list of software mentioned, I'd say that Mercurial isn't even installed (but yes, the error message gives away its version). The aspect of image as text is luckily corrected by now - it was another aspect. (But it's also ok to disagree: I'm coming from the Apache httpd side, where this question is odd IMHO). I probably should have pointed to [ask] as well, as your other comment hints at.

Comment: @OlafKock thanks, and the OP may appreciate your feedback. I agree there are important details missing but I also like to give a newer user some time to hopefully edit & add to the Q. I was mainly thinking that if it really is an HG problem then assuming enough other details are added it probably would be on-topic.;

Comment: @StayOnTarget sounds good. I've retracted my close vote, and removed the [tag:apache] and [tag:ubuntu] tags as they're irrelevant for the question. And according to those tags' definitions the question would be off topic. I'm fine with it being on topic with the other tags.

Answer (score -1):

1. Don't store **any** repo in remote share, you'll have a lot of different headache with additional (not needed) networking layer.
2. All "Server data" is irrelevant to problem of Samba-shares